# Test if an equivalence statement is transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We are told that $(x,y)\in R$ iff $|x+y|=|x|+|y|$ and that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've created the two statements:
$$(x,y) \in R \Rightarrow|x+y| = |x|+|y|$$
$$(y,z) \in R \Rightarrow|y+z| = |y|+|z|$$
But im not sure on how to proceed. I know I have to test for $(x,z) \in R \Rightarrow|x+z| = |x|+|z|$ i tried subbing the two equations into $(x,z)$, but I had no luck with that. Any thoughts?

Comment: $|5+0| = |5|+|0|$  and $|0+(-5)| = |0|+|-5|$ so $(5,0)\in \mathcal{R}$ and $(0,-5)\in\mathcal{R}$ but...

Comment: You can't prove it because its false; what does it mean for $x$ and $y$ to be related here?

Comment: You can prove this true if you reduce the space of consideration to $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

It helps to recognize when and where you can rephrase relations to something that is in more natural language.

Recognize that the relation $(x,y)\in\mathcal{R} \iff |x+y|=|x|+|y|$ can be rephrased as "*$x$ and $y$ have the same sign or at least one of $x,y$ is zero*"

"Has the same sign" is a great equivalence relation, but our relation is not quite that... it has that pesky "or one of them is zero" in there.  Indeed, when looking at zero in particular you are led to an example showing why the relation is not transitive.  $(5,0)$ and $(0,-5)$ both are in the relation but $(5,-5)$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this statement is false (i. e. relation is not transitive). Indeed, if $x=1$, $y=0$ and $z=-1$ we have that $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$ but $(x,z)\notin R$.